# Reset of reactive form removes disabled fields

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

How to prevent removing disabled fields while reset.
This is part of my code:

```
this.updateInformationForm = this.fb.group({
  'first_name': [first_name, Validators.required],
  'last_name': [last_name, Validators.required],
  'address1': [address1, Validators.required],
  'address2': [address2, Validators.required],
  'city': [city, Validators.required],
  'state': [state, Validators.required],
  'zip': [zip, Validators.required],
  'phone': [phone, Validators.required],
  'dob': [dob, Validators.required],
  'gender': [gender, Validators.required],
  'email': [email, Validators.required],
});

this.updateInformationForm.controls['first_name'].disable();
this.updateInformationForm.controls['last_name'].disable();
this.updateInformationForm.controls['email'].disable();
```

and my reset method:

```
  clear(): void {
    this.updateInformationForm.reset();
  }
```

Comment: Can you not put the disabling fields mechanism in a method, then also call that, just after the reset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your disabling when you build the form instead. Assumingly here you don't want to set any default values when resetting, but just emptying all fields, but if you initially set a field as disabled when building the form, it will stay disabled after reset:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.updateInformationForm = this.fb.group({
    // set as disabled already here!
    first_name: [{ value: 'first name', disabled: true }],
    last_name: ['last name']
  });
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kw2umt?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: @eddy Old answer, but seems to be working just as should even when using angular 9: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w3xm5k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: this solution doesn't work anymore on the DEMO. 'first name' also gets reset.